# How to set custom font for foundation button

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I am trying to set a custom font-family for the button in foundation 6 with no luck I am running foundation 6 with sass and believe they have removed the `$button-font-family` variable that was in previous versions. What is the best solution to achieve this without the variable?

Ideally I would like to apply a text-transform on the button text as well which is also not a button variable in the _setting.sass foundation file. As you may have gathered I am very new to foundation and sass so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like a font-family is specified in `scss/components/_button.scss` and that's where button syles are defined. The `$body-font-family` is set in both `scss/settings/_settings.scss` as well as `scss/_global.scss` (if not already defined in `_settings.scss`). So, verify that you have updated the value of `$body-font-family` there.

Aside from that, if you are using foundation sass semantically (i.e. mixins), you should be able to use the `button` mixin like so:

```
@include button( false, #ebebeb, #a5a5a5, black, solid );
```

..and then set the font-family property *after* the mixin like you normally would.

**----Update: Based on follow up question/comment----**

Here's an example main sass file for one of the foundation sites I'm working on now.

```
// Author copy of Foundation settings/_settings.scss
@import "settings";

// Author copy of Foundation _globals.scss
@import "global";

// Import from Foundation
@import "path/to/foundation-sites/scss/grid/grid";
@import "path/to/foundation-sites/scss/typography/typography";
@import "path/to/foundation-sites/scss/components/button";

// Include Foundation classes/styles that we want to use
@include foundation-global-styles();
@include foundation-typography();

//
// Author Variables
//
$color-map : ( 'blue': #40578a, 'blue-tint': #7e8ba8, 'blue-shade': #364a75, 'dark': #3d3e41, 'silver': #bdc0c6, 'gold': #ab883c );
$blue      : map-get($color-map, 'blue');
$blue-tint : map-get($color-map, 'blue-tint');
$blue-shade: map-get($color-map, 'blue-shade');
$dark      : map-get($color-map, 'dark');
$silver    : map-get($color-map, 'silver');
$gold      : map-get($color-map, 'gold');
//
// Author Components
//
@import "common";
@import "btn";
@import "view";
@import "cover";
@import "header";
@import "hero";
@import "navbar";
@import "main";
@import "page";
@import "intro";
@import "services";
```

I'll go through this section by section. It's pretty simple and once you have a project set up this way, you'll love it.

> // Author copy of Foundation settings/_settings.scss

Here, we are importing a copy of the Foundation _settings.scss file and modifying it for our needs. Don't mess with the original _settings file that ships with Foundation. Doing so will make it more difficult to update the library moving forward.

> // Author copy of Foundation _globals.scss

Same concept as the _settings file.

> // Import from Foundation

These imports are the only parts of the Foundation framework that I want to use in this case. These component files include the mixins used to generate these components. This allows us to use the mixins semantically in our code.

> // Include Foundation classes/styles that we want to use

And this will output the pre-defined classes/styles that we want to use from foundation. Typically, you will at least want to include global and typography styles.

> // Author Variables

This is where I put my custom variables (not related to Foundation). You could put this in another partial if you want - just a preference.

> // Author components

These are the project's custom components which may or may not utilize Foundation's mixins. The point is, we can if we want to now that we have included the components/mixins we want to use.

So, in your case, you could simply do this:

```
// Foundation settings
@import "settings";

// Foundation globals
@import "global";

// Import from Foundation
@import "../path/to/foundation-sites/scss/components/button";

//
// Author Variables
//
$special-button-font: Georgia, serif;

.special-button {
    @include button(false, #ebebeb, #a5a5a5, black, solid);
    font-family: $special-button-font;
    &.tiny     { font-size: map-get($button-sizes, tiny); }
    &.small    { font-size: map-get($button-sizes, small); }
    &.large    { font-size: map-get($button-sizes, large); }
    &.expanded { @include button-expand; }
}
```

Comment: I have changed my $body-font-family in the _settings file however I want the button font to be different to that. Would the solution be to go into `scss/components/_button.scss`and add the $button-font-family variable or is it not as straightforward as that?

Comment: Well...it is as straight forward as that BUT you should leave the foundation library as is and create your own `_settings` file that overrides the default settings. That way you can easily update foundation in the future without losing your custom styles. I'll update my answer to elaborate a bit.

Comment: I believe I do a have _setting override in place but when I add the  `$button-font-family ` variable in there it does not change the button font. I have tried your solution with the custom class with a mixin which works however I was hoping to use the size function which comes with the button class for example `<div class="large-12 large-centered">
      <a href="#" class="button large">Default Button</a>
     </div>`

Comment: You can use the button sizes just like Foundation does. I updated the example to show this. Read through the _button.scss file comments and you'll probably find a lot of helpful information.

Comment: Oh and Foundation does not use a variable called $button-font-family. If you want to use that variable you need to place it where I have placed $special-button-font.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help the updated solution works perfectly and the way you set up foundation seems a lot more simplistic to the set up I have right now.